# How do I mark a .jar file as executable on Xubuntu 13.04?

Tags: 13.04, xubuntu, minecraft, chmod

I'm trying to get the minecraft.jar file to execute , but the check box won't come up when I go to Properties > Permissions. I don't know much about the terminal and its commands so if someone could post a simple step by step solution on how to mark it that would be great.
People keep saying to use a chmod command but I have no idea what that is, so you are forewarned if I say "over my head".

Comment: jars don't need to be executable.  you can launch them with an interpreter just like python and have a launcher script (which I think is the generally accepted practice).

Comment: Have you tried right clicking the jar, and selecting "Open With > OpenJDK (or whatever java)"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming the file in question is in your $HOME (just move it with the GUI otherwise), open a terminal (that much should be easy :) then run this command:

```
chmod a+x jarfile.jar
```

Change `jarfile.jar` to the actual name of the file in question of course. If that gives you an error, the file is probably not owned by your user, so try again with `sudo`:

```
sudo chmod a+x jarfile.jar
```

Comment: Files in your home directory should not be owned by root

Comment: It worked perfectly!

Comment: @terdon Iknow it says I have to wait 5 minuets

Comment: and I need 15 rep

Comment: @minerz029 that depends on who put them there. There is nothing that _stops_ them from being owned by root. Try `sudo touch foo; ls -l foo`.

Comment: I said *should* not. With normal use, nothing in your home folder should be owned by anyone except yourself.

Comment: @minerz029 I understood that to be a prescriptive should rather than a hypothetical :). Anyway, that's not entirely true, there are various things that can end up in your $HOME, try `find ~/ -user root`, you might be surprised.

Answer (score 1):

Jar files are supposed to be executed like I've shown below (assuming you have configured JRE/JDK in the execution search path):

`java -jar /path/to/jarfile.jar`

You **CANNOT** directly execute a JAR file even if you add the execute bit. By itself `bash` is simply not able to understand it.

A simple shell script will be ideal to run Minecraft, for example:

```sh
#!/bin/bash
java -Xms1024M -Xmx1024M -jar /path/to/mincraft.jar
```

Comment: You are able to mark it as executable then open it with a double click. You just need to associate the MIME type with Java JRE

Comment: This is desktop environment specific, not flexible if JVM arguments need to be passed;-) But you are right anyway, double click executes jar files in DE/WM.

Comment: WHat about [self-extracting](http://www.javaworld.com/javatips/jw-javatip120.html) jar files?

Answer (score 0):

Open a terminal with Ctrl+Alt+T, then type

```
chmod +x /path/to/jar_file.jar
```

If the check doesn't come up, it might be on a Windows filesystem, which wont work

Comment: I have had it work on 12.04 before but not this time so I don't know what to do.

Comment: @Ben Is it on your system drive or a external disk?

Answer (score 0):

1. Simply press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>
2. type:

   ```
   java -Xms1024M -Xmx1024M -jar (copy and paste path to minecraft.jar)/Minecraft.jar
   ```
3. Enjoy